# jQuery Formula posts 'NaN' although each value is cast

Tags: jquery

I have a table produced dynamically with each row producing something like this:

```
 <tr name="0">
  <td style="text-align:left;">January</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LIB1" value="0" class="oneInput row0" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="RPI1" value="0" class="oneInput row0" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LMM1" value="0" class="oneInput row0" /></td>
  <td><b><span class="screenOneTotal">0</span></b></td>
</tr>
```

I need to put the total of each input in the row in the last column when a value is input. Therefore, I placed this function in the document.ready function

```
$(".oneInput").live('blur', function(){
 var rowID = $(this).parent().parent().attr( 'name' );
 var thisLIB = $("input[name=LIB + rowID]" ).val();
 var thisRPI = $("input[name=RPI + rowID]").val();
 var thisLMM = $("input[name=LMM + rowID]").val();
 var rowTotal = parseFloat(thisLIB) + parseFloat(thisRPI) + parseFloat(thisLMM);
 $(this).parent().parent().find( 'span.screenOneTotal').empty().html( parseFloat(rowTotal) );
});
```

Despite the fact that I am explicitly casting each value to a float, the value inserted into the last column is "NaN".

Comment: I'm sure that you can narrow down the issue with Firebug, to find out at which stage in calculation the `NaN` first appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things (and undercomplicating them at the same time). Your over-complication is that you're looking for three specific things and treating them individually when you could just grab everything that fits a certain pattern and treat them as a group. Your under-complication is that you're not considering failure conditions from `parseFloat` and the odd (until you're used to it) behavior of NaN.

I think you'd be better off going up the DOM to find the containing `<tr>` and the iterating through all the `.oneInput` elements in that row, then you can use one small chunk of code to convert the string values to sensible numbers the same way:

```
$(".oneInput").live('blur', function() {
    var $row     = $(this).closest('tr');
    var rowTotal = 0;
    $row.find('input.oneInput').each(function() {
        var n = parseFloat(this.value);
        if(!isNaN(n))
            rowTotal += n;
    });
    // Do whatever you need to do with rowTotal
});
```

The [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) call will go up the DOM to find the containing `<tr>`, then the [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will get all the `<input>` elements in that row that have a class of `oneInput`, then loop over those with [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each), extract each value straight from the `<input>` DOM element with [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), and add them to a running total in `rowTotal` if `parseFloat` finds a number (and [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) is the what you want to check if `parseFloat` handed you a NaN).

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DBQL3/

Comment: I HOPE that I can learn jQuery as well as that ... this will truly be study fodder. Thanks to all and thanks for showing me a new tool --- jsfiddle!

Comment: Though your fiddle includes it, your answer completely ignores the lack of `<table>` which causes the main issue.

Comment: @Tomalak: "I have a table produced dynamically with each row producing something like this", I took the HTML snippet to be a representational sample of the real HTML.

Comment: @mu: Yes, it was. And it was broken. And that was the bug.

Comment: actually, the original code contains table tags but since there are 13 rows and a header row, I omitted them for brevity

Comment: @Tomalak: There were several bugs but the biggest problem was that his code was simple where it should have been more complex and complex where it should have been simple. Reworking the whole thing solved it all by "giving the OP the solution that he actually needs".

Answer (score 3):

`$("input[name=LIB + rowID]" ).val()` does not look right.

Did you mean `$("input[name=LIB" + rowID + "]" ).val()`?

---

If your selector fails, then `.val()` is empty and `parseFloat` will give you `NaN`.

Comment: I think that the concatenation is the error BUT when I changed the three lines like you suggested, the last column value did not get hidden or replaced.

Comment: @jgravois: Demonstrable example please.

Comment: My formula is now $(".oneInput").live('blur', function(){
     var rowID = $(this).parent().parent().attr( 'name' );
     //alert( rowID );
     var thisLIB = $("input[name=LIB" + rowID + "]" ).val();
     var thisRPI = $("input[name=RPI" + rowID + "]" ).val();
     var thisLMM = $("input[name=LMM"+ rowID + "]" ).val();
     var rowTotal = parseFloat(thisLIB) + parseFloat(thisRPI) + parseFloat(thisLMM);
     $(this).parent().parent().find( 'span.screenOneTotal').empty().html( rowTotal );
});

Comment: @jgravois: Instead of a context-less and unformatted code dump, please provide a _demonstrable example_. Use http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: If I uncomment the alert, it works so jQuery seems to be working. BUT the value that was being replaced with NaN is not being changed at all

Comment: @john: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/qUzzw/) when I wrap everything in a `<table>` tag to make it valid HTML, and add `parseFloat` back in.

Comment: @john: Yes. You can't throw `<tr>`s and `<td>`s around without a `<table>` and expect things to work.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tomalak's answer, an attribute selector should also be enclosed in quotes.  Your example also shows that the row's name attribute is `0` but its children are LIB1, LPT1 and LMM1 so they need to be under a row with `name='1'`

```
var thisLIB = $("input[name='LIB" + rowID+"']" ).val();
```

Comment: This is a tiny excerpt from a payroll budgeting application I am writing for work. The fiscal months are in an array that is zero-based but I store all of the values with a null for the [0] value so when I output I have to add +1 to the fiscalVariable